# Why can't I do List<X<Long>> as a parameter for List<X<?>>

Tags: java, generics

I have a method that takes a `List<X<?>>`.  When I try to pass it a `List<X<Long>>` it fails to compile.  Why?

Comment: Could you show us the actual code that's failing, and the compilation error message?

Comment: You should declare your method as `<T> foo(List<X<T>> arg)` instead of `foo(List<X<?>>)`.

Answer (score 2):

A `List<X<Long>>` doesn't count as a `List<X<?>>`. Consider the `add` method of `List<X<?>>`. It takes an argument of type `X<?>`, and `X<Integer>` counts as `X<?>`. If we could pass a `List<X<Long>>` to your method, we could do

```
public static void foo(List<X<?>> arg) {
    arg.add(new X<Integer>());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo(new ArrayList<X<Integer>>());
}
```

and we'd add an `X<Integer>` to a `List<X<Long>>`, violating type safety.

Instead of taking a `List<X<?>>`, make your method generic:

```
public static void <T> foo(List<X<T>> arg) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics are invariant with respect to the type parameter. `List<X<Long>>` is not a subtype of `List<X<?>>` even though `X<Long>` is a subtype of `X<?>`, just like how `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>` even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`.

If you want to be able to take arguments with different type arguments, you can use a wildcard at the top level:

```
void foo(List<? extends X<?>> arg) {
    ...
}
```